# Talking about properties of "random" elements

Tags: measure-theory

This may be a very vague question, I apologize in advance.

Suppose that we have some set $X$ and we want to say that a "random"  (or generic) element 
of $X$ has some property, say $P$.

As far as I understand one way of doing this is to put a probability measure $\mu$ on $X$ and
show that the elements of $X$ having property $P$ are of $\mu$ measure $1$.

Of course this will heavily depend on the measure one has. If, for example there is   $x\in X$ with property $P$, and one takes the point measure
$\mu=\delta_x$, then a "random" element will have property $P$. This, being mathematically  perfectly fine, intuitively is not as nice since $x$ may be
the only element in $X$ with property $P$.

My question is what kind of model would be considered as a "nice" model
for a random element of a set $X$? In other words, 
what type of property of $\mu$ would make the sentence "A $\mu$ random element of $X$ has property $P$" interesting?

Comment: Do you have any applications in mind?

Comment: You might want something like $|A|\le |B| \implies \mu(A)\le\mu(B)$.

Comment: Or something like $|A^c|\le |A|\implies \mu(A)\not = 0$

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker I do not have a particular application in mind and I was expecting (hoping) that people will immediately suggest some standard properties.

Comment: @Vernon Usually, the underlying parameter space has some additional structure (topological, linear etc) that should agree with the notion of genericity.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Yes I undestand $X$ here can be a topological space and we can require the measure to be a Borel measure etc.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I have trivialized your question, for which I apologize.

A measure $\mu$ mapping a $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ over some set $X$ satisfies

1. $\mu\geq 0$
2. $\mu\left(\emptyset\right)=0$
3. For pairwise disjoint sets $X_i$ in $\Sigma$, $\mu\left(\bigcup_{i=0}^\infty X_i\right)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \mu\left(X_i\right)$

A probability measure satisfies the additional conditions

1. $\mu\left(X\right) = 1$
2. $\mu\leq 1$

The number $1$ is arbitrary. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space

I feel as though imposing any other restrictions prunes otherwise useful cases. Intuitively, there are lots of measures that satisfy the requirements, but are not particularly useful in this context (the point measure, as you suggested).